# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'log' during Mask RCNN implementation

Tags: google-colaboratory, faster-rcnn

I tried changing log to math.log and downgraded tensorflow version to 1.4 But still got the error.Can someone Please help.Thank you.
AttributeError: in user code:

```
/content/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py:390 call  *
    roi_level = log2_graph(tf.sqrt(h * w) / (224.0 / tf.sqrt(image_area)))
/content/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py:341 log2_graph  *
    return tf.log(x) / tf.log(2.0)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'log'
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to backward-compatibility.

It worked for me using `python 3.6` with the following requirements:

```
numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0
scipy
Pillow
cython
matplotlib
scikit-image>=0.14.2
tensorflow==1.15.3
keras==2.2.4
opencv-python
h5py
imgaug
```